Could not convert symbol to string error after adding https certificate
I am trying to fetch data from asp.net core api to svelte page. I got a self signed certificate error:
TypeError: fetch failed
    at node:internal/deps/undici/undici:12500:13
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  [cause]: Error: self-signed certificate
      at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (node:_tls_wrap:1674:34)
      at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:520:28)
      at TLSSocket._finishInit (node:_tls_wrap:1085:8)
      at ssl.onhandshakedone (node:_tls_wrap:871:12)
      at TLSWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
    code: 'DEPTH_ZERO_SELF_SIGNED_CERT'
  }
}

Next I used mkcert to create a certificate and key inside the project directory and then I updated vite.config.ts to look like this:
import { sveltekit } from '@sveltejs/kit/vite';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import fs from 'fs';

export default defineConfig({

    plugins: [sveltekit()],
    server: {
        https: {
            key: fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/cert/key.pem`),
            cert: fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/cert/cert.pem`)
        }
    }
});

Finally, when I start the sveltekit server I am greeted with this error in the browser:
TypeError: Could not convert argument of type symbol to string.
    at webidl.converters.DOMString (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1940:15)
    at webidl.converters.ByteString (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1945:35)
    at Object.record<ByteString, ByteString> (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1857:30)
    at webidl.converters.HeadersInit (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:3397:67)
    at Object.RequestInit (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:1914:21)
    at new Request (node:internal/deps/undici/undici:4821:34)
    at getRequest (file:///C:/path/to/project/Client/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/node/index.js:107:9)
    at file:///path/to/project/Client/node_modules/@sveltejs/kit/src/exports/vite/dev/index.js:497:2

BTW mkcert -install informed me that firefox is not supported on my platform.
Setting up the certificate for dev environment seems like a simple task, but I've been frustrated that I can't actually develop the website for quite some time now.
I want to fetch data from asp.net core api to a sveltekit front end, but I can't, because I get errors from which I can't make any sense.

Ran into this issue myself just now. I found that adding proxy: {} to the server object fixed it somehow.
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: ...,
    server: {
        https: {
            key: ...,
            cert: ...
        },
        // this line fixes it *somehow*
        proxy: {},
    }
});


Since writing this question I've decided to not use Svelte or any other frontend framework and just stick to ASP.NET Core's MVC. I can't check if this would work for me, so I'll just mark your answer as accepted.
